# Subsetting rows with specific character string

Tags: r, subset

Following are 3 rows of a very big data set (data frame is named `a`):

```
1   [~http-bio-26600-exec-98] - Update_Listing_API SellerID
2   [~http-bio-26600-exec-10] - Update_Listing_API SellerID
3   [~http-bio-26600-exec-40] - Update_Listing SellerID
```

I want to subset such that to get rows with string `"Update_Listing_API"` in them. I tried using `grep` function as:

```
a$v1 <- grep("Update_Listing_API", a$V1, invert = TRUE)
```

But it's giving me error as:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "V1", value = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L,  : 
  replacement has 637156 rows, data has 712410
```

Can somebody point the mistake here? I am new to R and don't know what's am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Does this accomplish your goal?  (I'm not sure if you want that `invert`)

```
    a <- a[grep("Update_Listing_API", a$V1, invert = TRUE),]
```

Comment: "I want to subset such that to get rows with string "Update_Listing_API" in them", pretty sure the OP doesn't want `invert`  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I created an example data frame to reproduce your problem:

```
#example data
data <- data.frame(x1=c("hallo_andi","hello_andi","hello_max","hallo_max"),x2=c("de","en","en","de"))

> data
          x1 x2
1 hallo_andi de
2 hello_andi en
3  hello_max en
4  hallo_max de

#subset with specific string

subset(data, grepl("hallo", data[[1]]), drop = TRUE)

          x1 x2
1 hallo_andi de
4  hallo_max de
```

Does this represent your problem?

In your case you can go with:

```
subset(a, grepl("Update_Listing_API", a[[1]]), drop=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your data looks like the following, a data frame with one column:

```
                                                      V1
1  [~http-bio-26600-exec-98] - Update_Listing_API SellerID
2  [~http-bio-26600-exec-10] - Update_Listing_API SellerID
3  [~http-bio-26600-exec-40] - Update_Listing SellerID
```

Your command   `grep("Update_Listing_API", a$V1, invert = TRUE)` prints out the indices that do not match the "Update_Listing_API" because of the `invert=TRUE` argument as Rick a few minutes ago already noted.

What you want is `grep("Update_Listing_API", a$V1, invert = FALSE)`. The error message that you received told you that you were trying to put a shorter vector (with the subset indices) in the longer, original data frame.